# Cannot use instance member 'getA' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, class, variables, swift3

Y this giving this error - Cannot use instance member 'getA' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

```
class A  {

    var asd : String  = getA()

    func getA() -> String {
        return "A"

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: var asd = getA() should work

Comment: Why are you storing it like that? Why not just do `var asd = "A"`.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but y its giving me error

Comment: Because you need `self` to exist to use `getA`. The error is self-explanatory.

Comment: @vaibby it would be easier to give you a solution if you show us your actual code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Property initializer run before `self` is available.

The solution is to `lazy initialize` the property:

```
class A {
    lazy var asd: String  = getA()

    func getA() -> String {
        return "A"
    }
}
```

That will initialize the property first time you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to initialize your asd variable. Then in the `init` you can apply your function value to it.

```
class A  {
var asd : String = ""

init() {
    self.asd = self.getA()
}

func getA() -> String {
    return "A"

} }
```